# i add a ssl cer and redirect http to https but now all url are 404

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

this is my nginx conf for project 
please say me why it doesn't work

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8037;
}
server {
server_name                        ;
listen        :80;
return 301 https://www.                 $request_uri;
}
server {
   listen 443 ssl;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.crt/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key/server.key;

server_name                               ;

charset   utf-8;
server_tokens       off;
access_log /etc/nginx/log/access.log;

error_log /etc/nginx/log/error.log;

location /static/ {
    alias   /home/app/public_html/Vishka/env/repo/project/Vishka/static/;
}


location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass django;
}
}
```

in uwsgi log there is no request 
all of my requests will be lose
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YKOA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was because of that a sub domain has been set to my server and i refer the main domain in ssl setting

Answer (score 0):

Check at server with port 80 at the scheme

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
```

Make sure also that configuration has valid syntax

```
listen       80 default_server;
listen       [::]:80 default_server;

listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
```